# Problems curling from PHP - Spring 3 REST PUT/POST methods using @RequestParameter parameters

Tags: java, php, web-services, spring, rest

I have created a very simple controller for a REST services using the Spring Framework. I have no problems using the @PathVariable in conjunction with GETs but when I try to create a POST or PUT, I am unable to curl the function and am trying to figure out where I have gone wrong.

```
@Controller
public class TestController {


    @RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public String putName(@RequestParam("name") String name, @RequestParam("value") String value) {

        System.out.println("Name - " + name);
        System.out.println("Value - " + value);


        return "You entered " + name + " with value of " + value;
    }
}
```

Editing this a bit to include some PHP since that is ultimately where I want to be calling this from.

If I do the following, it works as expected:

```
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://localhost:8080/RestService/test');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 120);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 120);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'name=some random name&value=just a value');
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
```

But if I try to pass the parameters as an array, I receive an HTTP Status 400 -The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect.

```
    $data = array
    (
        'name' => 'some random name',
        'value' => 'just a value'
    );

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://localhost:8080/RestService/test');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 120);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 120);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    $result2 = curl_exec($ch);
```

If I can at all help it, I do not want to be building strings, worrying about escaping ampersands, and etc out of the data I want to pass.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you try this command `curl --data "name=test" http://localhost:8080/RestService/test` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use **http_build_query**

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data));
```

Comment: That does work for the POST - but if I change the method to PUT on the server side, and make the appropriate change client side, both all forms return the HTTP Status 400 -The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect.

Am I doing something wrong server side??

Comment: Do you have any Spring Security configuration for this method? Perhaps there's an intercept-url configured to allow POST but not PUT?

Comment: If I do, it is not intentional. Would that be in the context xml file?